# Garbage collector heap memory

Tags: testing, load

Why is a performance tester asked questions related garbage collector heap memory or thread during the interview.. Aren't these related to performance tuning? Whenever there was memory leak during the endurance tests I have always informed the developer regarding it, I have done nothing to improve the memory myself..Is it really necessary for a performance tester to do all those by default? Or it depends on the project requirements? Well now I have read about these things online for my next interview but still just curious about how other performance testers work.

Comment: What's the question? I'm confused.

Comment: Should a performance tester know how to handle garbage collector, heap memory threads etc..? Because whenever I find memory leak or page fault error in my current project I just inform the DevOps team to handle it..we basically don't have access to fix any of those.but in my interview they ask questions related to GC , heap..